# In FsCheck, how to generate a test record with non-negative fields?

Tags: f#, fscheck

In F#, I have a record with a few fields:

```
    type myRecord = { a:float; b:float; c:float }
```

I am using FsCheck to test some properties which use this record.
For (a contrived) example,

```
    let verify_this_property (r:myRecord) = myFunction(r) = (r.a * r.b) / r.c
```

Due to the internal implementation restrictions of **myFunction**, I would like to have FsCheck create test cases in which each of the fields a,b,c are restricted to non-negative floats.

I suspect this requires creating a generator for **myRecord**, but I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this.

Can anyone supply guidance?

Comment: Have you carefully read [this FsCheck Wiki page](http://fscheck.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Test%20Data%20Generators&referringTitle=Home)? It has an example of how to write and register a generator.

Comment: @fmr--Yes I have carefully read all the FsCheck Wiki pages.  While the steps for writing a simple generator are provided (not very clearly IMHO), I am unable to determine how to extend this to create a generator for records -- hence, the SO question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
type Generators = 
    static member arbMyRecord =
        fun (a,b,c) -> { myRecord.a = a; b = b; c = c }
        <!> (Arb.generate<float> |> Gen.suchThat ((<) 0.) |> Gen.three)
        |> Arb.fromGen

Arb.register<Generators>() |> ignore
Check.Quick verify_this_property
```

The `<!>` is an infix `map`, useful for applicative style. This is an equivalent generator:

```
type Generators = 
    static member arbMyRecord =
        Arb.generate<float> 
        |> Gen.suchThat ((<) 0.) 
        |> Gen.three
        |> Gen.map (fun (a,b,c) -> { myRecord.a = a; b = b; c = c })
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

If you don't want to globally register your generator, you can use `forAll`:

```
Check.Quick (forAll Generators.arbMyRecord verify_this_property)
```

Shrinking left as an exercise ;)

Comment: What's the meaning of the "<!>" construct? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @DavidH : it's an infix `map`, useful for applicative style. See http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/12/zipping-with-applicative-functors-in-f.html

Comment: @DavidH : explained a bit more.

Comment: where does forAll live? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @Maslow and others that looked for this: `forAll` lives in the `Prop` module. Also, It seems that `Gen.suchAt` is deprecated, and `where` or `filter` should be used instead

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid creating custom generator by using [FsCheck conditional properties](http://fscheck.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Properties&referringTitle=Home)

```
let verify_this_property (r:myRecord) =
    (r.a > 0.0 && r.b > 0.0 && r.c > 0.0) ==> lazy (myFunction r = (r.a * r.b) * r.c)
```

Though this will result in (substantially?) slower execution of the test since FsCheck will have to discard all unsuitable test entries.