# How do I write a FsCheck generator for an interface in C#

Tags: c#, fscheck

Suppose I have an interface IPerson with 2 read properties age (int) and name (string).

I also have a class Person implementing IPerson.

How do I write a FsCheck generator for generating instances of IPerson type?

Comment: Define "generator for IPerson"

Comment: I mean generator in the FsCheck meaning: https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html

Comment: Don't quite understand why this downvoted or being closed as unclear. It's a reasonably clear question unless you don't know what FsCheck is, but in that case just move along, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the below should work:

```
Gen<IPerson> gen = from age in Arb.Default.Int32().Generator
                   from name in Arb.Default.String().Generator
                   select new Person(age, name) as IPerson;
```

Comment: It works, indeed. But how can you use the "from" clause on Arb.Default.Int32().Generator, as IGen<int> does not implement IEnumerable<int>. What 's the magic?

Comment: LINQ syntax works on any type that implements certain methods (Select, SelectMany, GroupBy etc), not just IEnumerable. Gen implements some of those.